# How to render parent's head tags on refreshing child in Nuxt JS?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have parent and child pages in following setup

- dashboard/
- --child1.vue
- --child2.vue
- dashboard.vue

My code in dashboard.vue:

```
<template>

  <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <admin-navbar></admin-navbar>
      <main-sidebar></main-sidebar>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <NuxtChild />
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    head() {
      return {
        link: [
          {
            rel: "stylesheet",
            href: "https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"
          },
          {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            href: '../adminPanel/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
          },
          
        ],

        script: [
          {
            src: '../adminPanel/dist/js/adminlte.js',
            body: true
          },
          {
            src: '../adminPanel/dist/js/demo.js',
            body: true
          },
          {
            src: '../adminPanel/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js',
            body: true
          },
        ],
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

In the MainSidebar.vue component, i have the following:

```
<template>
 <li class="nav-item">
            <NuxtLink to="/vendor/dashboard/child1">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
            Child1
            </NuxtLink>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <NuxtLink to="/vendor/dashboard/child2">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
            Child2
            </NuxtLink>
          </li>
</template>
```

In this setup, everything is working perfectly till I refresh the page while in child page. When I am refreshing any of the child page, the link and scripts which are defined in the dashboard.vue, not working anymore. I am getting the html part of the dashboard.vue file, not the head scripts for style and js. **How can I define them in such way they work even if I refresh the child page?**

One roundabout is declaring the style and scripts links in nuxt.config.js file. But i don't want to use these globally. only for this Page and the children.

Another solution might be using the same link and script array variable in all my child pages. but obviously that won't be efficient I think.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute paths are not a stable and reliable solution , instead use the `@` or `~` operators for referencing the static resources . Also `head()` is not the proper method for referencing the internal/local static files ( except external file URLs )

***Note*** That in the `Nuxt` you should put static stuff in the `assets` directory

> The assets directory contains your uncompiled assets such as your styles, images, or fonts.

For example if you want to import a CSS file in a specific component I'd suggest to do that this way

`component_1.vue`

```html
<style src="@/assets/adminPanel/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" scoped>
</style>
```

Or even for JS files :

```html
<script>
import "@/assets/adminPanel/dist/js/adminlte.js" ;
export default {
// ...
}
</script>
```

For custom JS scripts you can also use Nuxt [plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins) or [middlewares](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware) directory for having global scripts

Comment: Ok. Trying these. Will let  know if works or not.

Comment: script importing not working like that. and not sure if to use nuxt plugins. as that will add the scripts globally.

Comment: @adeab I updated my answer . just import the script with the file address `import * as` is used for creating a root variable for accessing to the all variables and methods and etc of that script anyway both solutions works for me

Comment: Nope...still doesn't work. anyway, I solved it. Posting the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was as I was using '../' to indicate the js and css files, from the child the directory was indicating wrong folder as '../' means one directory up and from child page it needed to be '../../'. So, as the files are in static folder (as per Nuxt JS documentation direction) I need to use a common syntax that always indicates the Static Folder. usually just using '/' indicates static folder, but as i have nested path, '/' it was not working properly till Nuxt JS documentation showed me the way to use '/' to idicate static folder even from a nested path. Just needed to include this in my nuxt.config.js. Source: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/static/

```
static: {
    prefix: false
  }
```

Now instead of '../adminPanel/...', i am using './adminPanel/...' and it is indicating the static folder from any page!